# Custom Buttons in Windows Mobile SDK 6

Tags: c#, windows-mobile, compact-framework

Is there a way to change the appearance of a button to use an image in Visual Studio Windows Mobile development.

I have tried using a picture box but found the event handler was very slow to execute.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you measure that "event handler was very slow to execute"?

Comment: When the picture box was clicked, the emulator was very unresponsive and took several seconds to do anything. Using a button, the same command is done almost instantaneously.

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty common beginner question.  So common, in fact, that [MSDN has an article covering the solution](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446518.aspx).